# change terminal window default location

Tags: terminal, x11, gnome-terminal, window-management

How do I change the default `gnome-terminal` location on **screen**. I checked out the preferences but they only have option to change default size. I also checked out `.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/` but didnt find any thing out.
All in all my `gnome-terminal` should normally be `gnome-terminal --geometry=80x24+200+200`
I dont want to do it through launcher because I will always have to start the terminal from launcher to get that location.

Comment: What window-manager are you using? (`wmcrtl -m`)

Comment: no such command

Comment: Then install it or get your WM name by other means!

Comment: @don-crissti yes.. will do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only the `sublime` plugin that's bothering you, you just have to edit the plugin preferences and add the geometry parameters:

> Preferences > Package settings > Terminal > Settings - Default

```
{   "terminal": "",
    "parameters": ["--geometry", "80x24+200+200"]   
}
```

---

Another way, if you also want `Alt-F2` to open a terminal at that location:
`gnome-shell` `Alt+F2` runs commands in your `$PATH` so you could create a new executable (e.g.`gterm`) somewhere in your `$PATH` (e.g. `/usr/local/bin`).
Edit `/usr/local/bin/gterm` like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec gnome-terminal --geometry 80x24+200+200
```

make it executable:

`chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gterm`

Now you can run `gterm` via `Alt+F2`, it will open a terminal @80x24+200+200. You can also point `sublime` to `gterm` (note there's no need for parameters anymore since `gterm` is already a custom size/position terminal):

> Preferences > Package settings > Terminal > Settings - Default

```
{   "terminal": "gterm",
    "parameters": []    
}
```

Comment: @don-crissti Great answer man.. Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps change your gnome-terminal.desktop file (not sure about the file name),

And set the Exec= line to `gnome-terminal --working-directory=/path/to/folder --geometry=80x24+200+200` instead, that way when you open a new instance, it would be in the desired folder already.

Comment: plz check the edited question

Comment: @KaunteyaSuryawanshi updated, you can merge the two command line arguments

Comment: Not working. And I dont need --working-directory

Comment: I guess the problem with editing .desktop file is that it will only work when we launch the terminal by clicking on the terminal icon..

Comment: @KaunteyaSuryawanshi What other method do you use?

Comment: Alt + F2. I also have added the terminal plugin in sublime2 so I frequently call it from there also. Whenever I press the key combination in sublime editor the terminal pops up exactly above the side bar. Which is exactly why I asked this question.